# How many height function on a given compact oriantable manifold there exist up to $SO(n)$ rotations?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, rotations, morse-theory

How many height function on a given compact oriantable manifold  there exist up to $SO(n)$ rotations? It seems to me that there is only one height function, but I have no Idea how to show it.

Comment: There are many many many. They are an open set in the space of all function, for example.

Comment: To easily get infinitely many, take your favorite height function and translate it.